# Why do I get "multiple definition" errors when compiling my project?

Tags: c, linker-errors

Edit : initializing the constants of my project in a C module and declaring them in a corresponding header resolved the issue.

I am working on making a C implementation of the AES cipher (link : https://github.com/SuperTotoGo/AES_Cipher). Everything was working fine until I tried to separate my project in modules. Now when I compile I get this error :

```
gcc -std=c99 -g -o aes.out *.c 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpeYNuO.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:8: multiple definition of `AES_SUB_BOX'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:8: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpeYNuO.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:28: multiple definition of `INV_AES_SUB_BOX'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:28: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpeYNuO.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:48: multiple definition of `AES_LOG_TABLE'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:48: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpeYNuO.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:68: multiple definition of `AES_ALOG_TABLE'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:68: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpeYNuO.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:88: multiple definition of `AES_MULT_MAT'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:88: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpeYNuO.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:96: multiple definition of `INV_AES_MULT_MAT'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:96: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpeYNuO.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:104: multiple definition of `RCON'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:104: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczfD784.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:8: multiple definition of `AES_SUB_BOX'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:8: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczfD784.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:28: multiple definition of `INV_AES_SUB_BOX'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:28: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczfD784.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:48: multiple definition of `AES_LOG_TABLE'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:48: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczfD784.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:68: multiple definition of `AES_ALOG_TABLE'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:68: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczfD784.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:88: multiple definition of `AES_MULT_MAT'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:88: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczfD784.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:96: multiple definition of `INV_AES_MULT_MAT'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:96: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczfD784.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:104: multiple definition of `RCON'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:104: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxcDlRl.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:8: multiple definition of `AES_SUB_BOX'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:8: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxcDlRl.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:28: multiple definition of `INV_AES_SUB_BOX'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:28: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxcDlRl.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:48: multiple definition of `AES_LOG_TABLE'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:48: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxcDlRl.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:68: multiple definition of `AES_ALOG_TABLE'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:68: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxcDlRl.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:88: multiple definition of `AES_MULT_MAT'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:88: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxcDlRl.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:96: multiple definition of `INV_AES_MULT_MAT'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:96: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxcDlRl.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:104: multiple definition of `RCON'; /tmp/ccHvhAUx.o:/home/pipou/AES_Cipher/aes_const.h:104: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My functions prototypes are defined in the headers and my functions are implemented in the corresponding c files, from what I understood about modular projects I normally only need to include the header files in the main file to have it working.

So, would you have any idea what I did wrong?

Also if you have any tips about making modular C projects or any advice conecerning how I have done it, please tell me!

Comment: I don't see *any* undefined reference error. Do you have include guards in your headers?

Comment: Your title says "undefined reference". The error messages say "multiple definition", which is essentially the _opposite_ problem. Where are you getting "undefined references" from?

Comment: @davmac Modified my post to show an other error log but I cut the first part by error. And I left just after. Sorry

Comment: @SuperTotoGo ok but your log here _still_ only shows "multiple definition" errors and the title _still_ says "undefined reference". Please update one or the other according to the problem you're actually having.

Comment: @davmac I found my solution, this question was poorly formulated. It was a problem with the initialization of my constants which I did in a header file included in multiple module.

Comment: @SuperTotoGo I'm glad you found a solution, but you are missing my point - having acknowledged that your question is poorly formulated, you should edit it so that it is no longer poorly formulated. Otherwise it is likely to continue to receive downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @davmac oooh I didn't know I could edit the question itself. I'll do that right away.

Answer (score 5):

You have several variables defined in the aes_const.h header file.  As a result, each source file that is compiled has a *copy* of those variables.  So when everything in linked, you end up with multiple definitions.

Move these variable definitions into a single source file, then put `extern` declarations for them in the header file.

So the header should contain:

```
extern const uint8_t AES_SUB_BOX[16][16];
extern const uint8_t INV_AES_SUB_BOX[16][16];
extern const uint8_t AES_LOG_TABLE[16][16];
extern const uint8_t AES_ALOG_TABLE[16][16];
extern const uint8_t AES_MULT_MAT[4][4];
extern const uint8_t INV_AES_MULT_MAT[4][4];
extern uint8_t RCON[10];
```

And the existing definitions should be moved to a .c file, for example aes_const.c.

Comment: Also, either `RCON` should also be `const`, or it should be changed to a function-local variable for thread safety.

Comment: @SuperTotoGo The short version is, if `RCON` remains a global variable and ever gets _written_ to (which is the only reason it couldn't be `const` as well), that would make it unsafe to call your AES implementation from multiple threads simultaneously.  The long answer does not fit in the comment box, please ask a new question if it's still unclear to you what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @zwol I'm tired and stupid, didn't properly read your message, fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: @dbush Shouldn't my #ifndef #define prevent that?

Comment: It prevents a file from being included multiple times in a given source file.  It does not prevent multiple definitions between multiple flea compiled separately.

Answer (score 0):

The prototypes are defined in the headers, which is why the *compiler*  detects all the names and succeeds in compilation. The failure you're getting is during link-time. That is because the linker needs the *implementation* of the functions, which live in the .c files.
What you need to do is to compile all the .c files and link the resulting object files together. C projects usually build all the object files first (`gcc -c *.c`) and then link them all together in a separate step (`gcc -o aes.out *.o`)

Comment: "What you need to do is to compile all the .c files and link the resulting object files together" - that's what OP's command line does, though. " projects usually build all the object files first ... and then link them all together in a separate step" - true, but not actually necessary.